# Wrong answer in exercise but I don't know why. Do maps from $M$ to $K$ where $M$ is a set and $K$ is a field form a field itself?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Let $K$ be a field and $M$ be a random nonempty set and $S$ the set of all maps from $M$ to $K$ define where for $f,g \in S$ and $m \in M$ that we have  $(f+g)(m):=f(m)+g(m)$ and $(f \cdot g)(m):=f(m)\cdot g(m)$. Does $S$ form a field or not?

What I already could show is that in the case $K$ is a ring we have that $S$ is also a Ring. But in case we have a Field I argued that we can't have a field because let $f(m)=0$ for some $m$ then we can't define an inverse $f^{-1}$ since there is no multiplicative inverse for $0$. Why is this reasoning wrong?

Comment: The reasoning is correct. $S$ does not form a field.

Comment: Your reasoning makes sense if $|M|>1$ so that you can find $f\ne0$ with $f(m)=0$. If $|M|=1$ then $S$ is isomorphic to $K$.

Comment: I see... stupid mistake xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is essentially correct, but you need to slightly adjust your answer. (What if $M$ only has a single element?)